# Can't connect dbt to Databricks

Tags: databricks, dbt

I am trying to connect to a Spark cluster on Databricks and I am following this tutorial: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbt.html. And I have the `dbt-databricks` connector installed (https://github.com/databricks/dbt-databricks). However, no matter how I configure it, I keep getting "Database error, failed to connect" when I run `dbt test` / `dbt debug`.

This is my `profiles.yaml`:

```yaml
databricks_cluster:
  outputs:
    dev:
      connect_retries: 5
      connect_timeout: 60
      host: <my_server_hostname>
      http_path: <my_http_path>
      schema: default
      token: <my_token>
      type: databricks
  target: dev
```

This is my `dbt_project.yml`:

```yaml
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'dbt_dem'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'databricks_cluster'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


# Configuring models
# Full documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models

# In this example config, we tell dbt to build all models in the example/ directory
# as tables. These settings can be overridden in the individual model files
# using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  dbt_dem:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

I have also tried using the `spark` connector, but I still get the same error using that. Any ideas as to why I can't connect to the Databricks cluster?

These are the logs corresponding to the error:

```
============================== 2022-02-18 08:43:22.123066 | 4b91f9d3-28ad-4f5a-93db-f431b6d9af14 ==============================
08:43:22.123066 [info ] [MainThread]: Running with dbt=1.0.1
08:43:22.123841 [debug] [MainThread]: running dbt with arguments Namespace(cls=<class 'dbt.task.debug.DebugTask'>, config_dir=False, debug=None, defer=None, event_buffer_size=None, fail_fast=None, log_cache_events=False, log_format=None, partial_parse=None, printer_width=None, profile=None, profiles_dir='/Users/keremaslan/.dbt', project_dir=None, record_timing_info=None, rpc_method=None, send_anonymous_usage_stats=None, single_threaded=False, state=None, static_parser=None, target=None, use_colors=None, use_experimental_parser=None, vars='{}', version_check=None, warn_error=None, which='debug', write_json=None)
08:43:22.124057 [debug] [MainThread]: Tracking: tracking
08:43:22.143750 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'start', 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fb751ef42e0>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fb751ef4eb0>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fb751eca730>]}
08:43:22.236001 [debug] [MainThread]: Executing "git --help"
08:43:22.264682 [debug] [MainThread]: STDOUT: "b"usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]\n           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]\n           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]\n           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]\n           <command> [<args>]\n\nThese are common Git commands used in various situations:\n\nstart a working area (see also: git help tutorial)\n   clone             Clone a repository into a new directory\n   init              Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one\n\nwork on the current change (see also: git help everyday)\n   add               Add file contents to the index\n   mv                Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink\n   restore           Restore working tree files\n   rm                Remove files from the working tree and from the index\n   sparse-checkout   Initialize and modify the sparse-checkout\n\nexamine the history and state (see also: git help revisions)\n   bisect            Use binary search to find the commit that introduced a bug\n   diff              Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc\n   grep              Print lines matching a pattern\n   log               Show commit logs\n   show              Show various types of objects\n   status            Show the working tree status\n\ngrow, mark and tweak your common history\n   branch            List, create, or delete branches\n   commit            Record changes to the repository\n   merge             Join two or more development histories together\n   rebase            Reapply commits on top of another base tip\n   reset             Reset current HEAD to the specified state\n   switch            Switch branches\n   tag               Create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG\n\ncollaborate (see also: git help workflows)\n   fetch             Download objects and refs from another repository\n   pull              Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch\n   push              Update remote refs along with associated objects\n\n'git help -a' and 'git help -g' list available subcommands and some\nconcept guides. See 'git help <command>' or 'git help <concept>'\nto read about a specific subcommand or concept.\nSee 'git help git' for an overview of the system.\n""
08:43:22.265387 [debug] [MainThread]: STDERR: "b''"
08:43:22.272505 [debug] [MainThread]: Acquiring new databricks connection "debug"
08:43:22.273434 [debug] [MainThread]: Using databricks connection "debug"
08:43:22.273833 [debug] [MainThread]: On debug: select 1 as id
08:43:22.274044 [debug] [MainThread]: Opening a new connection, currently in state init
08:43:22.888586 [debug] [MainThread]: Databricks adapter: Error while running:
select 1 as id
08:43:22.889031 [debug] [MainThread]: Databricks adapter: Database Error
  failed to connect
08:43:22.889905 [debug] [MainThread]: Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'end', 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fb751f7eaf0>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fb752113040>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x7fb7521130a0>]}
08:43:24.130154 [debug] [MainThread]: Connection 'debug' was properly closed.
```

Comment: do you have only this error, or maybe more detailed error? Maybe you can enable `dbt` with more verbose error messages?

Comment: I couldn't find a `--verbose` command, but I managed to find the corresponding logs. I am not sure if there is any useful information here.

Comment: yeah, isn't very helpful...

Comment: @k88 is the http type connection a hard requirement or are you open to using an ODBC connection type?

Comment: Also - not sure if it makes a difference but you may need to change the file name from `profiles.yaml` to `profiles.yml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not specified this in the original question, but I had used `conda` to set up a virtual environment. Somehow that doesn't work, so I'd recommend following the tutorial to the letter and use `pipenv`.

Comment: pyenv worked for me without doing anything special--for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Check your profiles.yml (usually found here: `~/.dbt/profiles.yml`)  and make sure there is:

1. No `https://` in the host name and
2. A leading slash in the http_path

For example:

```
host: server.name.com                              # instead of https://server.name.com
http_path: /sql/protocolv1/o/0/0000-000000-text000 # note the leading slash
```

These are easy mistakes to make if, like me, you copied the http_path straight out of the cluster config page and the host straight out of your browser URL.

Another example of profiles.yml from the dbt-databricks ReadMe: https://github.com/databricks/dbt-databricks